# how to serialize and deserialize a tuple

Tags: f#, datacontractjsonserializer

How to serialize a JSON to tuple within F# (and vice versa)?

JSON Schema

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "type": "document",
  "id": "e3c7373c-f4bc-4ffa-9a01-7c7d9f83e4cf"
}
```

Tuple

```
let document = ("test", "document", "e3c7373c-f4bc-4ffa-9a01-7c7d9f83e4cf")
```

Ideally using [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What JSON are you supposed to see for tuple `("test", "document")`?

Comment: sorry didn't get you, the question is about serializing JSON to tuple

Comment: My point is - there will be information loss. So this is not "serialization", because by definition "serialization" must be reconstructible.
For example:
`{"name": "test", "type": "doc" }` At best it has to be `(string * obj) * (string * obj)`/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Functions snipped from here:
// https://gist.github.com/theburningmonk/2071722

open System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

// I changed these two lines from using ASCII to using UTF8,
// for UNICODE support. This is also what Microsoft's similar
// examples use.
let toString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString
let toBytes (x : string) = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes x

let serializeJson<'a> (x : 'a) = 
    let jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typedefof<'a>)
    use stream = new MemoryStream()
    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, x)
    toString <| stream.ToArray()

let deserializeJson<'a> (json : string) =
    let jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typedefof<'a>)
    use stream = new MemoryStream(toBytes json)
    jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream) :?> 'a

// End of snip

[<CLIMutable>]
[<DataContract>]
type MyType = {
    [<DataMember>] name: string
    [<DataMember>] ``type``: string
    [<DataMember>] id: string
    }

let document = { name = "test"; ``type`` = "document"; id = "e3c7373c-f4bc-4ffa-9a01-7c7d9f83e4cf" }
let json = serializeJson<MyType> document
json.Dump() // LINQPad output

let json2 = """{"id":"e3c7373c-f4bc-4ffa-9a01-7c7d9f83e4cf","name":"test","type":"document"}"""
let document2 = deserializeJson<MyType> json2
document2.Dump() // LINQPad output
```

Comment: plus one for using LinqPad :D

Comment: it is not a tuple

Comment: true, but it's trivial to convert it to one: `(document2.id, document2.name, document2.``type``)`.